# Почему переменная не меняет значение?

Tags: python

Есть такой код:

```
def Stop():
    StopTool = False
    print(StopTool)

keyboard.add_hotkey('Alt', Stop)

while StopTool == True:
      s.Go()
```

Проблема такая: Метод `s.Go()` работает пока переменная `StopTool == True`. 
Я нажимаю `Alt`.  Функция `Stop` отрабатывает в самой функции `StopTool`.  Присваивается `False`.

Но сам цикл `while` не останавливается. 
Там всегда переменная `StopTool == True`

Что не так? 
Спасибо.

Comment: global StopTool

Comment: stop ведь вне цикла.он и не сработает

Comment: @КириллМалышев Не надо рекомендовать новичкам использовать global.

Comment: Ну да, а как без Global Тут?

Comment: @duddeniska, как минимум два варианта: 1 - возвращать значение из метода, и проверять его, 2 - изменять поле объекта и проверять его.

Comment: Да всем спасибо. Global помогло. Я новичок в Python не знал про это. Переменная была объявлена в самлом начале. Думал достаточно. Спасибо.